Explain the proof of Kolmogorov Arnold representation theorem
Can someone explain the outline of proof strategy of Kolmogorov Arnold representation theorem? Any proof of any variant (eg. George Lorentz's variant) would suffice. I would be grateful if you could explain in simple terms as I am only in undergraduate year 3.

I think this is a very accessible paper https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.00408

@TedBlack Thanks, shall I close the question?
